Calculate gradient with respect to data label in Pytorch
I'm working on implementing a technique from a research paper where I need to calculate gradients with respect to data labels. Here's the approach I'm following:

Calculate the gradient of the loss with respect to the model's parameters (grad1).
Calculate the gradient of grad1 with respect to the data labels.
However, I'm encountering an issue where the gradient with respect to the data labels is always None. It seems that the data labels (y) are not part of the computational graph (y.grad_fn returns None).
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.nn.utils import parameters_to_vector

class LeNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(LeNet, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 6, 5)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 5)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 5 * 5, 120)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv1(x)))
        x = self.pool(torch.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = x.view(-1, 16 * 5 * 5)
        x = torch.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

# Load CIFAR10 dataset
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))])
trainset = torchvision.datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=1, shuffle=True)

model = LeNet()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

# Get a batch of data
x, y = next(iter(trainloader))

y = y.float().requires_grad_(True)

output = model(x)
loss = criterion(output, y.long())

first_order_grads = torch.autograd.grad(loss, model.parameters(), create_graph=True)

Jm_list = []

for grad in first_order_grads:
    if grad is not None:
        for grad_element in parameters_to_vector(grad): 
            Jm = torch.autograd.grad(grad_element, y, retain_graph=True, allow_unused=True)[0]
            Jm_list.append(Jm)

I'm looking for advice on two points:
How can I include data labels in the computational graph?
Are there alternative methods to calculate gradients with respect to data labels effectively?
Any insights or references to similar implementations would be greatly appreciated!

loss = criterion(output, y.long()) by taking y.long(), you effectively disconnect y from computational graph again.
